# What is the difference between keyword, abbreviation and shortcut?

Tags: meaning

Are they all the same thing? or what is the difference between them?

For example

> using a keyword for presentation or while writing notes,

> using shortcuts for presentation or while writing notes,

> using abbreviations for presentation or while writing notes.

Here is what I know about them, shortcuts are a short way of writing words and abbreviations are also a short way of writing words and keywords are also a short way of writing words

Definition of shortcut is  "a route more direct than the one ordinarily taken" from Merriam-Webster

Definition of keyword is "A word used as a reference point for finding other words or information."  from the free dictionary

Definition of abbreviation is "a shortened form of a word or phrase." from oxford dictionary

so are all 3 of them the same thing?

Comment: What does your research reveal? **Keyword**: each term I passed to google. **Shortcut**: a key combination with a direct action, for example Ctrl-P to print. **Abbreviation**: *Ctrl* is an abbreviation of *Control*.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! We expect people to do a little research before askinga question. In this case, you could look up these three words in a good dictionary, for example this one: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keyword If that doesn't provide the information that you require, please edit your question to add details of your research, and to explain what exactly you still don't understand.

Comment: @JavaLatte, I don't really understand what you guys mean by details of research since I view all 3 of them as the same thing so should I just write that as the details of my research?

Comment: @user131592  You could copy and paste the definitions of the three words from your dictionary to the question.  Then say why the defintions seem to be the same.

Comment: @JamesK , well the problem is that I don't think that all 3 of them have the same meaning because of a dictionary but because of their usage and my understanding or intuition and also I can't give you the 3 words usage since I know it subconsciously and I don't know how to articulate it so what should I do in a case like this?

Comment: In this case, the meanings are so completely different.  The question is like asking "should I use car, bike, or train to say 'I go to school by car/bike/train'."  All are possible, but have different meanings, and a dictionary can tell you the meaning.  So you should not use your intuition, you should use a dictionary!

Comment: Here  is what I know about them, shortcuts are a short way of writing words and abbreviations are also a short way of writing words and keywords are also a short way of writing words

Comment: Well there we go!  You need to use a dictionary because "shortcuts" and "keywords" are not a short way of writing words!  Shortcut  means "an alternative route that is shorter than the one usually taken. Or an accelerated way of doing or achieving something". Keyword means "a word or concept of great significance."

Comment: I updated the question with the definitions should it be like this or should I also include the links?

Comment: If you use a keyword while making notes, it is an important word which you use to help you to remember a topic -  not an abbreviation.

Comment: Are abbreviations considered as a word? if so then abbreviations also remind you of the topic if you use them?

Comment: Well, you might abbreviate a keyword - or any other word - to save yourself the time and trouble of writing it out in full.

Comment: @pobig43001 They have related meanings, like car/bike/train, but they are used to describe different things, like car/bike/train. Perhaps you can give some examples that show how you think that the words could all be used to mean the same thing.

Comment: In your example, keywords can be used as shortcuts. In this case, they are used to mean the same thing - but they needn't always mean the same thing.